# HP UFT and LR are blocking execution of other IDEs

Tags: intellij-idea, loadrunner, hp-uft, katalon-studio

`IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition` and `Eclipse` cannot be started after UFT and LR are installed on `Windows 8.1`. These applications can be started only as an administrator user. When I try to execute as a standard user I don't get any error message, seemly nothing happens, application is not started. Applications can be executed as administrator user, but don't working properly. It means `Maven` dependencies aren't resolved in `IntelliJ IDEA` and browser session cannot be started by `Katalon Studio`. I can't find any error logs.

Comment: What makes you think that `uft` and `loadrunner` are **blocking** the access to the other IDEs?

Comment: @Dave : These were working before I installed uft and lr, so these should be the blocker, because anything else were changed on system.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  At a guess, I'd say some aspect of UFT or LR has overwritten something that the other tools rely on.  Might be worth reinstalling the other tools after UFT/LR are installed and see if all works in that scenario (one app may be requiring an older version of something and causing a problem that way).  If that doesn't work, you may have to consider installing the tools on separate machines.

Comment: Try checking the Windows event log if it contains any errors/warning at time you are trying to start the applications.

Comment: I think I had this issue before and it happened because LR came with a version of Java that was not compatible in very old version (11.X). That said, I have LR installed on my machine and I use several InteliJ products without issue (Windows 10)

Comment: @Buzzy : I removed UFT and applications are working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you install UFT/LR they update the JAVA OPTIONS

- **_JAVA_OPTIONS**: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1
  \classes;C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
- **IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS**: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1
  \classes;C:\PROGRA~1\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
- **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS**: -agentlib:jvmhook

Just make a batch file for launching `eclipse` and `intellij` and remove these hooks and it should work. These hooks are usually added for automation and recording to work. Most of the time they are supposed to be transparent and not create an issue but with some apps they may cause partial issues.

This could be the same happening. The easiest way to test is to backup the values of these environment variables and then delete them and test if IDE works fine again

Comment: Thanks for the solution to this issue!